# Api for video processing with Apache beam

Tags: video-processing, apache-beam

Currently I observe that `Apache Beam` is released for flexible Stream processing. I am searching for api to process video stream, but not found any. Can anyone please suggest about any video processing `API` with `Apache Beam`/ `Google Dataflow`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Beam is a general purpose programming model for distributed data processing. While Beam doesn't have "video processing APIs", it would be great for many video processing tasks, particularly those that parallelize effectively.

Typically, you'd want to use Beam along with a standard video processing library. Beam programming model can help you with the parallelization aspect and the video processing library can simplify the underlying task on a small section of the input.